# How to save formData from react class component?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-component

I include my code. Can you tell me how do I save? After clicking the save button FormData is null. How do upload images using the Cloudinary library and React class component? API is working properly. Body data pass to the API as form-data. This is my API response =>

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "success": true,
    "status": "OK",
    "ItemDetails": {
        "_id": "6125cc9ecfde9b2eb45d1909",
        "item_name": "Chicken Rices",
        "item_type": "Rice",
        "item_time": "Lunch",
        "item_price_type_small": 120,
        "item_price_type_medium": 170,
        "item_price_type_large": 200,
        "item_url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/doelyvv2h/image/upload/v1629867165/MenuList/ldmny2cxvhqh7fisy1ex.jpg",
        "cloudinary_id": "MenuList/ldmny2cxvhqh7fisy1ex",
        "createdAt": "2021-08-25T04:52:46.726Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-08-25T04:52:46.726Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    "message": "Item added successfully."
}
```

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import User from "../../../assets/images/user.png";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { APIURL } from "../../API/environment";

const initialState = {
  item_name: "",
  item_type: "",
  item_time: "",
  item_price_type_small: "",
  item_price_type_medium: "",
  item_price_type_large: "",
  image: "",
};

class AddFoodMenu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = initialState;
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let item_name = this.state.item_name;
    let item_type = this.state.item_type;
    let item_time = this.state.item_time;
    let item_price_type_small = this.state.item_price_type_small;
    let item_price_type_medium = this.state.item_price_type_medium;
    let item_price_type_large = this.state.item_price_type_large;
    let image = this.state.image;

    console.log("object", item_name);

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("item_name", item_name);
    formData.append("item_type", item_type);
    formData.append("item_time", item_time);
    formData.append("item_price_type_small", item_price_type_small);
    formData.append("item_price_type_medium", item_price_type_medium);
    formData.append("item_price_type_large", item_price_type_large);
    formData.append("image", image);

    console.log(formData);

    axios.post(`${APIURL}/menulist/add-item-to-menu`, 
      { method : "POST",
        body : formData}
    ).then((res) => {
      console.log("res", res);

      if (res.data.code === 200) {
        toast.success(res.data.message);
        window.setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = "/login";
        }, 2000);
      } else {
        toast.error(res.data.message);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Please add code for where you call onSubmit

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't understand you're question. Post full code or some more clarity.

My suggestion would be to set the value to a state with API response.